# $(#id).on() not working with dynamically created content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make script to create basic pop_up easily but I've a problem when I try to bind action to my created element.

here the code :

```
button.prototype.init_action = function()
{
 var i = 0;
 if (this._triger.length != this._action.length)
 {
     console.log('Il doit y avoir autant de triger que d\'action');
     return;
 }
 var name = '#' + this.prototype._idConteneur+'_'+this.prototype._name;
 while (i < this._triger.length)
 {
     console.log($(name).on(this._triger[i], this._action[i]));
     i++;
 }
}
```

Button is a pseudo class. it's inehrit from another object call windowObject.

this._triger is an array contening the action I want to bind.

here :

```
_triger = ['click']
```

And _action contain the function I want to bind.

Here :

```
_action[0] = function(){console.log('HI!')}
```

The code work pretty well, but the only problem is that .on() seem to do nothing.
When i click on the created button, nothing happen.
If rather than call init_action(), i Do the same code in console, it work
(basicly :

```
$("#button").on(_triger[0], _action[0])
```

) it work's totally fine.

Any idea?

ps : I've tried with .bind() rather than .on() and it change nothing

Comment: just google event delegation

Comment: Please refer http://api.jquery.com/on/ for any explanations. It has all the details that you need. I think you were mis-guided to stackoverflow for this question

Comment: If you use `.on()` on a dynamically added element, it will not work. You will have to bind it to a DOM object that is already present at runtime, e.g. the document object, so you should use `$(document).on('event', '#selector', function() {...});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead: http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$("body").on("event","#id",function(){
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thx, using $("body") instead of $("#id") make it work's fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(document).on("click")` event for handle click event of dynamically created content:

```
$(document).on("click","#id",function(){
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   $('#button').OnClick(function(){
    });
```

If you are calling your Click event